# ASP.NET Core 3 на хостинге Мастрехост

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, хостинг, asp.net-web-api

Приобрел хостинг мастерхост, через FTP загрузил билд своего Web API, подключил домен. Теперь, когда перехожу по домену, получаю ошибку:

> **401.3 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to an ACL set on the requested resource.**
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page due to the access control list (ACL) that is configured for this resource on the Web server.

Нужна помощь. Возможно я делаю что-то неправильно. Как правильно настроить работу ASP.NET Core 3 приложения на этом хостинге?

Comment: Там же все хостинги на ПХП!?

Comment: @Bulson в Windows хостингах заявлена поддержка NET CORE 2.2&3.0

Comment: Вы вперед выставляете IIS? У вас в ошибке жалоба на запрет доступа, который действует в конфигурации web server.